# Have a String [] composed by other String []

Tags: java, string

I'm implementing a timetable for a scholar use. 
I'd like to have a `String []` object that has ALL the subjects erogated in a week.
I thinked to append every `String [] dailySubjects` (that I have) to a`String []` object (that we can call `weekSubjects`). 
In logical plan it's simple to see. But I've tried to implement and I'm having no results.
How can I do? there is not an `add` method for `String[]`. That method would make all easier.
By the way,
My code

```
public Class getWeekSubjects () {
    public getWeekSubjects () {
        //this is a String [] composed by all the subject in a day
        String dailySubjects [] = new timetable().getDailySubjects;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to use a Collection like ArrayList that is a dynamically sized array with methods for add, remove, etc.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow, where also noob like me can write to understand an unknown language. If I knew what you show off, I wouldn't write here to keep your downvote. Ah, you would not comment simply to make fun of someone.

Comment: I would say that the previous comment is not for Averroes, but for another user that removed his one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it right, you have a method for getting the daily subjects, and now you want to put all the week subjects in an array.

But what if daily subjects repeat? (Math on Monday, math on Tuesday.) In that case you would want to have a Set, not an array.

```
public String[] getWeekSubjects() {
    Set<String> weekSubjects = new HashSet<String>();
    String[] dailySubjects = new timetable().getDailySubjects();
    Collections.addAll(weekSubjects, dailySubjects);

    // Add the other daily subjects... (somehow)    
    return weekSubjects.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

By the way, the code you posted is horrendous... If that is what your actual code looks like, then you have bigger problems to deal with.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is probably the most useful answer because it will fix his logic....

Comment: I have implemented a set for every day. It would be useful to have a set for all the week. But.. how can I do this?

Comment: don't worry for the downvote, i kept it to 0 again ;)
By the way, first of all thank you. Can you explain me what are you doing with the upper code? the string  `Set<String> weekSubjects = new HashSet<String>();` what does it do?

Comment: It creates a new set (HashSet) of Strings. But seeing how you don't understand this code... I think you ought to read the Java tutorials: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html

Answer (score 1):

[ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) best suits in your situation I think. Also you should use [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) when you do append.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays have a fixed length. You can either (a) use an `ArrayList`, which does not have a fixed length, or (b) create a new array large enough to hold all the data and use `System.arraycopy()` to copy your values in.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a `List<String>` or something, is there a hard requirement you have to use `String[]`??

Comment: why the downvote? `ArrayList` is one implementation of `List` interface, you should know that if you want to implement applications correctly you should make use of the proper data structures according to your requirements; and indeed, a good practice is to declare them by its interface, that will give you flexibility choosing/changing the implementation later...

Comment: I've understood what are you saying. I think that the downvote is son of the superficiality with whom some users read.
I remedy: i keep your answer to 0 again.
Ah, thank you for your answer